# replace a certain string in a file - sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

The problem is there is a file with many strings like `$VARx$` and `x` stands for a number from 1 to 9: `$VAR1$`, `$VAR2$`, `$VAR3$`, etc.

I want to quote these strings like `$VARx$` → `"$VARx$"`. I read or know that this could be possible with sed out of the command line but I have no idea how. Something like that but don't work:

```
sed -i "s/\\\$VAR1\$/\"\$VAR1\"\$/g" file.txt
```

The special part would be to include the variable `x`.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
sed -i 's/\$VAR[[:digit:]]\+\$/"&"/g' file.txt
```

`[[:digit:]]\+` matches 1 or more digits.
`&` represents the matching string.

GNU sed manual:
http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative using `sed` :

```
sed -i 's/\(\$VAR[1-9]\$\)/"\1"/g' file.txt
```

This solution seems a bit closer to the PO's specification :

> a file with many strings like `$VARx$` and x stands for a number from 1 to 9.

=> `[1-9]` matches only one digit between 1 and 9.

In this example, I also wanted to show the use of capturing parentheses : `\1` corresponds to the first expression captured by the capturing parentheses (`\(...\)`). Of course, `&` work as well for this case :

```
sed -i 's/\$VAR[1-9]\$/"&"/g' file.txt
```

Be careful: `-i` will do the substitution directly into the file instead of standard output.

Comment: Does not work. If i paste this into my cli and change the filename the command works but within the file nothing has changed.